# Permission for library to create folders

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, document-library, permissions, folder

I have the following requirements and don't know how to tackle it.

1. Allow create folders under the root of the library
2. No upload under the root of the library (user must be in a folder to upload files)

How can I achieve this with permission setting?

Comment: What is the functionality required if somebody uploads to the root? Should we  prevent such an operation completely ? Or do you want to move the item automatically to a folder if someone uploads at the root?

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think that is possible. If you allow users to create folders under root folder of the library, they will be able to create documents at the same level.

As a workaround, you can set as following:

1. Create the folders at root level for the users and then disable the ability to create new folder in this library.
2. Give **View Only**/**Read** permission to all users at library level.
3. Give **Contribute** or above permission to users at subfolder level.

Answer (score 0):

1. For allowing users to create folders, you have to set the right option in the library parameters then advanced parameters then scroll down to folder options : allow to use New Folder option
2. I don't know if it's possible...

Comment: That is already there. user with edit/contribute can create folders. the requirement is user with proper permissions can create new folder for a given project. they are not allowed to upload files under the root of a document library.